# Using Powershell I need to manipulate a text file to store in an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, text-files

I have a text file that looks like this.

```
COMPUTER1 Source-Port 445
COMPUTER1 Dest-PORT 54542
COMPUTER1 protocol tcp
COMPUTER2 Source-Port 12345
COMPUTER2 Dest-PORT 45782
COMPUTER2 protocol udp
COMPUTER3 Source-Port 1025
COMPUTER3 Dest-PORT 11125
COMPUTER3 protocol tcp
```

I want the output to look like this

```
Computer   SourcePort  DestinationPort  Protocol
Computer1  445         54542            tcp
Computer2  12345       45782            udp
Computer3  1025        11125            tcp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not pretty and there may well be a more 'idiomatic' solution.

```
$sourceFilePath = "path_to_source_file"
$destFilePath = "path_to_destination_file"

$fileContent = Get-Content -Path $sourceFilePath

$portInfo = @()

Get-Content -Path $sourceFilePath | 
    ForEach-Object {

        # Split the line and assign to variables
        $compName, $paramName, $paramValue = ( $_ -split " " )

        # Translate parameter names
        if ( $paramName -eq "source-port" ) { $paramName = "SourcePort" }
        if ( $paramName -eq "dest-port" ) { $paramName = "DestinationPort" }

        # Check for an existing object for this computer
        $object = $portInfo | ? { $_.Computer -eq $compName }

        # If no existing object, create a new one
        if ( ! $object ) { 
            $object = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{"Computer"=$compName} 
            $portInfo += $object
        }

        # Add in current parameter
        $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $paramName -Value $paramValue

    }

# Send consolidated objects to file
$portInfo | 
    Format-Table -Property Computer, SourcePort, DestinationPort, Protocol |
    out-file -FilePath $destFilePath
```